# forever and forever-monitor

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

The github pages are really light on documentation. I know everybody loves forever, but I'm confused about what the difference between `forever` and `forever-monitor` actually is, and which package I should be using under which circumstances.

Do they offer the same functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated in the [README of forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#readme) and [README of forever-monitor](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor#readme) the `forever` module is the Command Line Interface and the package `forever-monitor` is the core monitoring functionality without the CLI so you can use it *programatically*.

#### Which package I should be using under which circumstances?

- You should use the `forever` module when you want to use the CLI(starting something manually for example).
- You should use the `forever-monitor` when you are writing a program that should control the application you are starting. For example an app where you start other apps in via an interface or if you want to spawn something that should be restarted on failure in your app.

#### Do they offer the same functionality?

I haven't looked throughout the code but the `package.json` file's dependencies in the `forever` module includes `forever-monitor`, which sounds realistic because the `forever` module is an application which controls other applications (and therefore uses `forever-monitor`). So probably (at least most of it) yes, but everything in `forever-monitor` might not be implemented in `forever`.

Comment: @StevenLu, no response.. Did my post helped you?

Comment: i havent had time to get back to getting my server online :/ Appreciate the answer though!